# Crash when trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I'm new to Linux and trying to set up a dual boot Ubuntu / Windows 10 system on a new Dell xps x8900.

Each time I get midway through the boot-up process before I can even install, the system crashes into this:

https://goo.gl/photos/rypQ1DHbCDgpWQa38

I've tried multiple different downloads to make sure that my isos aren't corrupted, and I've tried booting from both DVDs and USB sticks.

help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot into the live cd (click try Ubuntu without installing) but [pass the kernel this parameter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options): `pci=noaer` to disable PCIE Advanced Error Reporting. If you can get booted then you can try to find out which PCIE device is causing the errors.  It is hard to tell from the video you posted what is actually going on in detail.  You may also consider checking what values (for PCIE) can be adjusted in your system's bios.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should specify what version of Ubuntu you are trying to install (I would guess it is 16.04), and if possible what PCIE devices you have in your Dell